# La columna obligatoria 'correo electrónico' no estaba presente en los resultados de una operación 'FromSql'. '

Tags: c#, mysql, base-de-datos, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Primero que nada pido disculpa si no me expreso correctamente o no utilizo los terminos tecnicos, Actualmente soy estudiante de programacion y base de datos[nivel basico].

Tengo un problema estoy tratando de realizar una consulta basica con SQL Puro, a una base de datos MySQL utilizando C# .net core desde una aplicacion de consola.

- Link del tutorial que estoy siguiendo

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html

Me descargue la base de datos:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

- Le aplique scaffold a mi base de datos existen:

  dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=mypass;database=sakila" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -o sakila -f

Mi primera consulta hacia una base de SQL:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using sakilaConsole.Models;
namespace sakilaConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            using (var context = new classicmodelsContext())
            {
                var EmployeesList = context.Employees.FromSqlRaw(
                    "SELECT * FROM Employees"
                ).ToList();
                foreach (var item in EmployeesList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[Emplyee Number]:" + item.EmployeeNumber);
                    Console.WriteLine("[Emplyee First Name]: " + item.FirstName);
                    Console.WriteLine("[Emplyee Last Name]: " + item.LastName);
                    Console.WriteLine("_________________________");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Salida n...:

```
[Emplyee Number]:1702
[Emplyee First Name]: Martin
[Emplyee Last Name]: Gerard
_________________________
```

Todo bien hasta el momento pero que sucede, Yo no quiero traerme todos los campos de la tabla Employee solo con los que necesite trabajar.

Quiero que mi consulta quede así:

```
var EmployeesList = context.Employees.FromSqlRaw(
    "SELECT EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName FROM employees ORDER BY employeeNumber"
).ToList();
```

Pero me da error:

```
English:
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll: 'The required column 'email' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.'
    
Spanish:
La columna requerida 'email' no estaba presente en los resultados de una operación 'FromSql'
```

Si hago la consulta directa mediante PhpMyAdmin si la realiza.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando trabajo con asp.net core en una aplicacion web en el formulario si no lleno los campos que son requeridos me da error, claro que da error por que los campos son requeridos, pero yo no estoy registrando informacion estoy haciendo una consulta.
A que se debe esto? que estoy haciendo mal? me pueden orientar por favor.
Y gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una limitación de usar raw query. [Limitaciones raw query](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations)

Creando un tipo anónimo puedes obtener el mismo resultado.

```
var EmployeesList = context.Employees.Select(e => new {
      e.EmployeeNumber,
      e.FirstName,
      e.LastName
    
    })
    .OrderBy(e => e.EmployeeNumber)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Como harias esa misma consulta sin usar tipo anonimo?

Comment: Una opción sería agregar un valor por defecto al email en la consulta SQL para satisfacer la condición del email requerido: `SELECT EmployeeNumber, FirstName, LastName, 'e@e.c' as Email FROM employees ` Y la otra forma es usando un DTO como indica la otra respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, crear una clase Dto la cual llevaría solo los campos que quieres mostrar.

```
        public class EmployeeDto
        {
            public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }
```

Luego solo realizas la consulta de esta manera:

```
var EmployeesList = context.Employees
                .Select(e=> new EmployeeDto
                 {
                    EmployeeNumber = e.EmployeeNumber,
                    FirstName = e.FirstName,
                    LastName = e.LastName

                 }).OrderBy(e => e.EmployeeNumber)
                   .ToList();
```

También puedes usar un objeto anónimo, te va funcionar en el contexto actual, pero si lo usas desde un método externo (usando repositorios u otro patrón) no te seria muy útil ya que no sabrás que propiedades tiene ese objeto.